# SharePoint html script editor snippet issue on Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sharepoint

So I have some html that I've been placing into the script editor web part on SharePoint. It looks good on Chrome SharePoint & it looks correct on my local server on Explorer 11...

But the number text shifts to the right of each button when viewing the SharePoint snippet in Explorer 11.

Here is what it looks like in the script editor webpart on Explorer:
[image]

Does anyone know if this is a SharePoint/Explorer issue or something because the snippet looks fine everywhere else? Thanks

This snippet is how it looks on my Explorer local server and Chrome/ Chrome Sharepoint

```css
 .grid {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:150vw;
            max-width: 150vh;
            /*height: 25vw;*/
            /*max-height: 25vh;*/
            font-size: 2rem;

        }
        
        .row1 {
            display: flex;
            float: center;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width:50vw;
            max-width: 50vh;
            /*height: 25vw;*/
            /*max-height: 25vh;*/
            font-size: 2rem;

        }
        .row2 {
            display: flex;

        }
        
        .box {
            background: #003b5c;
            margin: 5px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            position: relative;
        }
        
        .box:after {
            content: "";
            float: left;
            display: block;
            padding-top: 100%;
        }
        
        .box > div {
           
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            top: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        }
        
        /*  Apply images here */

        .topblock {
            background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");           
        }
        .leftblock {
            background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
        }
        .midblock {
            background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
        }
        .rightblock {
            background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
        }

        /* Hover effect*/

        .section {
            align-items: center;
            text-align: center;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #7a9bac79;
            transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
            margin: 0.5em; /* Increased margin since the box-shado expands outside the element, like outline */
        }


        .section:hover {
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px #ffc72c;
        }
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="row1">
            <!-- Link and Title -->
            <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="topblock" href=""><h4 style="color:white;">1</h4></div>               
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="grid">
        <div class="row2">
            <!-- Link and Title -->
            <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="leftblock"><h4 style="color:white;">2</h4></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Link and Title -->
            <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="midblock"><h4 style="color:white;">3</h4></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Link and Title -->
            <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
                <div class="rightblock"><h4 style="color:white;">4</h4></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the Style below in your code.

```
.section h4{
    margin:0px !important;
}
```

**Full code**:

```
<style type="text/css">
.grid {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:150vw;
    max-width: 150vh;
    /*height: 25vw;*/
    /*max-height: 25vh;*/
    font-size: 2rem;

}

.row1 {
    display: flex;
    float: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50vw;
    max-width: 50vh;
    /*height: 25vw;*/
    /*max-height: 25vh;*/
    font-size: 2rem;

}
.row2 {
    display: flex;

}

.box {
    background: #003b5c;
    margin: 5px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.box:after {
    content: "";
    float: left;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.box > div {

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(36, 36, 36), 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

/*  Apply images here */

.topblock {
    background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");           
}
.leftblock {
    background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
}
.midblock {
    background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
}
.rightblock {
    background-image: url("https://media1.tenor.com/images/16ffa7fc3ca750fd6f64eaf577e529c5/tenor.gif?itemid=7422720");
}

/* Hover effect*/
.section {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #7a9bac79;
    transition: box-shadow 0.2s linear;
    margin: 0.5em; /* Increased margin since the box-shado expands outside the element, like outline */
}
.section:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px #ffc72c;
}
.section h4{
    margin:0px !important;
}
</style>

<div class="row1">
    <!-- Link and Title -->
    <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <div class="topblock" href=""><h4 style="color:white;">1</h4></div>               
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="row2">
        <!-- Link and Title -->
        <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <div class="leftblock"><h4 style="color:white;">2</h4></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Link and Title -->
        <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <div class="midblock"><h4 style="color:white;">3</h4></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Link and Title -->
        <div class="box section" onclick="location.href='https://google.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <div class="rightblock"><h4 style="color:white;">4</h4></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]